# Simple MouseMove handling

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, gdi

I try to write a simple graphical editor. I have next problem, when i'm painting some curve using `SolidBrush()`, I get the interrupted one (look image). I need to get uninterrupted curve. I try to use capture of mouse for this, but it doesn't work (result the same). How I can fix it? Look code below for MouseMove event handler:

```
void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isMouseDown)
            {
                pictureBox1.Capture = true; // I try to capture mouse here
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.pictureBox1.Handle);
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.X, e.Y, 1, 1);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the speed of your mouse moves, sometimes MouseMove event will fire more often and sometimes not. I think it also depends how much is your machine loaded at that particular moemnt. If you draw lines between two points they won't be curved but straight. Instead you should look at [Beziers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve.) and [Splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29). That way you will get curves based on few points.

But you could do something with your code. Whenever the distance between your last mousedown and current mousedown event is greater than a threshold (you can get that empirically), you can add new dot(s) to your curve.
below is the example code which is adding one dot:

```
 public bool isMouseDown { get; set; }
        Point lastPoint = Point.Empty;
        public double treshold { get; set; }
        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isMouseDown)
            {
                pictureBox1.Capture = true; // I try to capture mouse here
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.pictureBox1.Handle);
                if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(e.X - lastPoint.X, 2) + Math.Pow(e.Y - lastPoint.Y, 2)) > treshold)
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), (e.X + lastPoint.X)/2, (e.Y + lastPoint.Y)/2, 1, 1);

                }

                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.X, e.Y, 1, 1);
                lastPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isMouseDown = true;
            lastPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isMouseDown = false;
        }
```

Comment: I'm knowing that I can do it using polynomial algorithms such as Bezier, but cann't I do it drawing the point? Doesn't it possible?

Comment: @Vsevywniy Based on my experience, you can't influence the rate how many mousemove events will be raised. Also there is no minimal distance that will trigger mousemove. Therefore you will get interrupted curves.

Comment: When I'm painting in standart windows Paint graph editor using pencil tool, I get uninterrupted curve. Does it mean that it formed using polinomials algorithms such as Bezier?

Comment: @Vsevywniy Check the edited answer. I think that they just use some tricks like the one I edited in my answer so the user can't notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't draw points, instead, remember your last mouse position, and draw line from it to the current mouse position.

Comment: No, because mouse moves aren't on pixel-by-pixel basis.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem of mouse move you have another, more serious problem here.

Using `Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.pictureBox1.Handle)` and drawing directly on the graphics surface will be temporary as the pixels will disappear.

Bob Powell also has a very good answer for this.

See his #1 most asked GDI+ question: https://web.archive.org/web/20131226033137/http://bobpowell.net/picturebox.aspx